# Intermittent timeout for cron job to another server that is serving ok?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an app engine project. I have a cron task that will try to open a url (on another server I own, running jetty), every 15 minutes:

```
<cron>
  <url>/pingjetty</url>
  <description>Jetty up check.</description>
  <schedule>every 15 minutes</schedule>
</cron>
```

I'll get a SocketTimeoutException 25% of the time. I know that the jetty instance is up and running when app engine reports the timeout. Looking at the jetty logs, it looks like these requests never reach it:

```
[28/Apr/2013:12:24:59 +0000] "GET /jettyapi/echo HTTP/1.1" 200 31 
[28/Apr/2013:12:40:03 +0000] "GET /jettyapi/echo HTTP/1.1" 200 31 
[28/Apr/2013:12:55:04 +0000] "GET /jettyapi/echo HTTP/1.1" 200 31 
---- missing entry, should be a connection attempt here around 13:10 -----
[28/Apr/2013:13:27:08 +0000] "GET /jettyapi/echo HTTP/1.1" 200 31 
[28/Apr/2013:13:42:09 +0000] "GET /jettyapi/echo HTTP/1.1" 200 31 
[28/Apr/2013:13:57:09 +0000] "GET /jettyapi/echo HTTP/1.1" 200 31
```

And just to be clear, here's the flow of things:

1. Cron job fires on my app engine instance, calling local servlet for /pingjetty.
2. This servlet tries to open url: "www.example.com/jettyapi/echo", which lives on my jetty instance.
3. The connection is fine 75% of the time - but 25% of the time I'll get the SocketTimeoutException. The exception is thrown from within the app engine servlet, trying to communicate with my jetty instance.

Is it possible that there's something going on from app engine's side? I've had this cron job running for the last two years and never saw this. I increased the connect and read timeouts to 60 seconds each. I'm also making sure the jetty instance is up and serving when the timeouts happen (other users are connecting to the jetty instance via their browsers when this timeout happens).

Any ideas would be great, not sure where to continue investigating,

Thanks

------- Update ---------------

I wasn't able to figure out what was going on. I just added a retry loop to my cron job as follows:

```
int tries = 3;
for (int i = 0; i < tries; i++) {
    try {
        openUrl("www.example.com/jettyapi/echo");
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException) {
        continue; // try again
    }
}
```

So the first attempt fails 25% like before, but the subsequent retries work fine. I haven't had a total failure since adding this. But it's still confusing.

Comment: everything seems ok: https://code.google.com/status/appengine

Comment: No idea what's wrong, but you might be better off by having the cron job enqueue a task every 15 minutes and let the processor for that task do the actual HTTP request to your server -- if the request fails, let your task processor return an 5xx error code and AppEngine will retry it.

Comment: I added a retry loop, which is masking the timeouts now. So the first one will fail in the loop, but the subsequent ones will get through ok. Still not sure what's going on, but this 'fixes' it for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Your Cron job first makes a request to the path /pingjetty in your App Engine App and then a Servlet in your App Engine app makes a request to your Jetty instance. Where are you seeing the error message? Are you seeing a stack trace in your App Engine application logs? This means that the Cron job is successfully firing and sending a request to your App Engine app.

Comment: Ah yes I didn't make this clear - the cron job is definitely firing, and the local servlet (which pings the jetty instance) is executed. It's that local servlet that is reporting the SocketTimeoutException.